# I cant get errors to show when validating a form with PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to validate a single textbox on the same page using PHP but am unable to get the errors to show. When i click submit and there is nothing in the textbox it works by not letting it go to the next page but it does not show the errors. Here is my code.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')    {
    if ($_POST['IGN'] == ""){
        $errors="Please enter a IGN";   
    }
    if (isset($errors)){
        echo $errors;   
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="Queston1.php">
<label for="IGN" class="questionText">IGN (In Game Name)</label><br />
<input type="text" name="IGN" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start" />
</form>
```

I have tried it with and without the `if (isset($errors))` to see if that was the problem but both times i get the same result.

Can anyone see or know how to fix this?

Comment: What does `Queston1.php` look like? Is it the same resource or another script that handles the form?

Comment: Try change this line `$_POST['IGN'] == ""` to `empty($_POST['IGN'])`

Comment: Please try some debugging. Add `var_dump(...)` statements in strategic locations to figure out what is going on in your code and which conditions are entered and which aren't. The code itself looks ok, you need to debug why it's not working in your particular case, we can't remote-debug it for you.

Comment: @Athafoud If you're using `empty` you don't need to also use `isset`.

Comment: @deceze correct! my mistake

Comment: @deceze i have done a 'var_dump($errors);' Under the echo errors part and both before and after submit is pressed it shows just NULL i have the same result with using both ways Athafoud suggested

Comment: Dump all the other variables step by step. At some point some value is not what you expect, so some code is not getting executed! Figure out where that is.

Comment: @deceze I done all of them they all did not produce anything from what they should. But i have got it working i moved just `echo $errors` down under the form and it worked. While using the `empty($_POST['IGN'])`

Comment: @Athafoud Thanks for your help the `empty($_POST['IGN'])` helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery or Javascript to validate before submitting the form.

But instead of

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
```

Try

```
$errors = '';
if(isset($_POST['IGN'])){
    if($_POST['IGN'] == ''){
        $errors .= 'Please Enter a IGN';
    }
}
if($errors!=''){
    echo $errors;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')    {
if ($_POST['IGN'] == ""){
  echo "Please enter a IGN";   
}

else {
    header('Location: question.php');
}


}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<label for="IGN" class="questionText">IGN (In Game Name)</label><br />
<input type="text" name="IGN" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start" />
</form>
```